# Cannot install Orange 3 ImportError: PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide are not available for import

Tags: python, pyqt4, orange

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have created a virtual environment and installed Orange using

```
pip install orange3
```

I also installed PyQt4 using

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

But when I launch orange3 from terminal I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/bin/orange-canvas", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Orange3', 'gui_scripts', 'orange-canvas')()
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2649, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2303, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2309, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/arun/lab/orange3/Orange/canvas/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from AnyQt.QtGui import QFont, QColor, QDesktopServices
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/AnyQt/QtGui.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _api
  File "/home/arun/.virtualenvs/orange3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/AnyQt/_api.py", line 96, in <module>
    raise ImportError("PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide are not available for import")
ImportError: PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide are not available for import
```

Comment: The problem with PyQt4 installed via APT not being seen by Orange is that the two things were likely installed in two different [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) (APT installs into a system environment). You can try to mitigate it by re-creating the virtual environment, but this time also passing `--system-site-packages` switch to `virtualenv`, or you could install Orange system-wide by skipping virtualenv step altogether.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you are missing a version of PyQt *in the [environment](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) you run Orange from*.

Best do something like `pip3 install pyqt5` in the same terminal you pip-installed Orange.

Comment: @K3--rnc: I have tried that too. But stuck with the following error. `(orange3env) arun@pc ~ $ pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.8-5.8.0-cp34.cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)`

Comment: Then I have installed sip from here: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download. But still getting the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1`.  Tried `pip3 install sip` too. But got `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip` error.

Comment: Seems like this should happen if you're on Python 3.4. Upgrade your Python, or you are left to build SIP from source.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu 14.04. When I create a virtualenv, the python version is 3.4. Can you tell me how can I upgrade python to 3.5?

Comment: Sure, easiest to upgrade Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Confirmed solution using python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me)

sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtsvg

https://thequickblog.com/orange3-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtsvg/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).