# PyQt4/5 in orange3 Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, orange

It was a great news that orange became a part of Python 3.x (`orange3`). However there are errors which I tried to communicate on GitHub without any luck. I wonder if anyone managed to fix this on:

```
Current conda install:

               platform : osx-64
          conda version : 4.3.25
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.25
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.14.2
```

Once you run orange3-canvas, soon you are getting a repeating message:

```
SystemError: unable to find to find module: PyQt4.QtCore
```

and depending on the stat-routine, sometimes a warning:

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
```

Similar question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697677/cannot-install-orange-3-importerror-pyqt4-pyqt5-or-pyside-are-not-available-fo), and I wonder whether someone managed to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try running below commands:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda update orange3

conda install -c defaults pyqt=5 qt
```

Reference: https://orange.biolab.si/download/linux/

Comment: Thanks so much! I followed suggested steps but I am getting the same warnings and error messages.